# How to represent multiple unique constraints across hierarchical tables?

Tags: postgresql, hierarchy, unique-constraint

My (shortened) table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE bus 
(
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name character varying NOT NULL CHECK (name<>'')
);

CREATE TABLE network_node  
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL CHECK (name<>''),
    ecu integer NOT NULL REFERENCES ecu,
    bus integer NOT NULL REFERENCES bus,
    UNIQUE(ecu,name),
    UNIQUE(bus,name),
);

CREATE TABLE controller_application 
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL CHECK (name<>''),
    network_node integer NOT NULL REFERENCES network_node,
    address smallint NOT NULL CHECK (name BETWEEN 0 AND 253),
    bus integer NOT NULL REFERENCES bus,
    UNIQUE(network_node,name),
    UNIQUE(bus,address),
);
```

The relationship I am trying to represent in the database is:

- A `bus` contains zero or multiple `network_node`s
- A `network_node` owns zero or multiple `controller_applications`
- Indirectly `controller_applications` relate to exactly one `bus`.
- An `ecu` contains zero or multiple `network_node`s

The constraints I am trying to represent in the database are:

- `network_node` `name`s have to be unique per `ecu`
- `network_node` `name`s have to be unique per `bus`
- The `address`es of the `controller_application`s have to be unique on each `bus`

You will also see that there is currently redundant hierarchical information in the structure, as `controller_applications` and `network_nodes` both contain the `bus` field.

Comment: You need to change the `(network_node)` FK ro include the `bus`. Something like: `FOREIGN KEY (bus, network_node) REFERENCES network_node (bus, id)` and add a unique constraint on `network_node (bus,id)` as well (for this new FK to work).

Comment: For the "problematic", you already have `UNIQUE(bus,address)`, where is the problem?

Comment: @ypercube Writing problematic was a bad idea. I give an example of a sequence which would produce inconsistent data.
<!-- language: lang-sql -->

    INSERT INTO network_node(id,name,ecu,bus) VALUES (1,'B1_NN1',1,1);
    INSERT INTO controller_application(id,name,network_node,address,bus) VALUES (1,'NN1_CA1',1,1);
    INSERT INTO controller_application(id,name,network_node,address,bus) VALUES (1,'NN1_CA1',1,2);

This obeys the constraints, but the `bus` given in the last `controller_application` is not the same as in the `network_node`.

Comment: correct. The suggestion I made in my first comment will avoid this issue. You won't be able to insert inconsistent (for this constraint) data.